# Java.IO.File to System.IO.Stream in C#?

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android

I am trying to move a part of code written in Java (Android) to C# (Mono for android) and I am stuck at finding a way to do this. The part of the code in Java is as follows:

```
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
     try {
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);
     ...
     } catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
     }
```

Precisely, converting from `Java.IO.File` to `System.IO.Stream` as required by the first parameter of [DecodeStream](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aAndroid.Graphics.BitmapFactory/M/DecodeStream) is my problem. How should this statement be rewritten?

Comment: Do you get an error? What is not working for you?

Comment: I have not been able to compile the code as it is, because I do not know how to write the decodeStream statement.

Comment: Let me ask another question: are you trying to write decodeFile or decodeStream? If it is the former: decodeStream is a Monodroid library or is it provided by  someone else?

Comment: `DecodeStream` is a standard function provided by the Android API. I have provided a link to it in my question. I just want to convert the function `decodeFile` in Java to C#.

Comment: @Cordera thanks, I got confused by your second comment: it seemed to me you needed to rewrite the decodeStream function itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use the static System.File methods to obtain the corresponding FileStream:

```
var stream = File.OpenRead("PathToFile")
```

In your case, you should get rid of the "File" class that you have in java: File is a static class in .NET. Can you pass the path directly (as a String) to your decodeFile function?

```
 private Bitmap decodeFile(string f){
 try {
    var o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(f)) {
      BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, o);
    ...
    }
 } catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
 }
```